# How can I get the IP address and hostname from HTTP request?

Tags: c#, http

I am using the following:

```
var myip = Request.UserHostAddress
```

but it says Request is not defined. I have included the reference `System.Wb.Mvc, System.Web.Abstractions`.

I have tried defining as follows:

```
var myip = (request as System.Web.HttpRequestBase).UserHostAddress;
```

but request is undefined. How can I define a new instance of request?

Comment: _"I have included the reference System.Web.Mvc"_ - umm, can you tell us more about your project? Is it ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Where do you want to get this? Filter, middleware, handler or controller?

Comment: It is an asp.net project and i want to get this from controller .

Comment: Does your controller class inherit from `Controller`?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var myIp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hongmeig1/how-to-access-the-clients-ip-address-in-web-api).

Comment: I have tried that but System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null .

Comment: Why should that be necessary in the controller?

Comment: @Mel, can you post the method where you are using this and update question

Comment: sorry let me give you more info. One project inherits from BaseController and BaseController inherits from Controller.   This project that is not working uses Winforms and doesnt inherit from Controller .. so is this possible ?

Comment: sorted thanks all; I deleted my references to system.web.mvc and system.web.extensions and retrieved from nuget and i used as above by Uwe.                                   
 var myIp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;